# Using Rx Repeat() and Replay() to cache and restart a DNS query

Tags: system.reactive

I'm a Rx newbie, so I hope you can bear with me.  As an exercise for myself, and possibly a sample I can demonstrate for colleagues, I've done two wrapper classes for Dns.BeginGetHostEntry()/EndGetHostEntry(): DnsResolver and DnsResolverRx.

The classes each have a single public static method:

```
void Resolve(string host, Action<IPHostEntry> getResult, Control context = null);
```

...and some additional requirements to make it interesting:
1. if context is provided, getResult must be invoked on the associated thread
2. previous results for the same host are cached for MaxResultAge seconds.

The non-Rx version works fine, but is not really relevant to this question.
The Rx version looks like this:

```
class DnsResolverRx
{
  static Func<string, IObservable<IPHostEntry>> _resolver = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<string, IPHostEntry>(Dns.BeginGetHostEntry, Dns.EndGetHostEntry);

  public static void Resolve(string host, Action<IPHostEntry> setResult, Control context = null)
  {
    IObservable<IPHostEntry> result;
    result = _cache.GetOrCreateValue( // a trivial TryGetValue wrapper
      host,
      () => _resolver(host)
        .Do(e => Debug.WriteLine("resolved"))
        .Repeat()
        .Do(e => Debug.WriteLine("repeated"))
        .Replay(MaxResultAge)
        .RefCount()
    );

    result = result.Take(1); // each request needs only 1 result

    if (context != null)
      result = result.ObserveOn(context);

    result.Subscribe(
      entry => setResult(entry),
      ex => setResult(null)
    );
  }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
  {
    int num = i;
    Debug.WriteLine("start" + num);
    DnsResolverRx.Resolve("chief", e => Debug.WriteLine("done"+num));
    Thread.Sleep(200);
  }

  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Replay() seems to work, so the first requests within MaxResultAge are all completed, reusing the same result.  However, the next request triggers Repeat(), and I end up with a seemingly endless loop:

```
start0
start1
start2
start3
start4
start5
resolved
repeated
done0
done1
done2
done3
done4
done5
start6
resolved
repeated
resolved
repeated
... and so on ad infinitum
```

Can anyone enlighten me on what's going on, and what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All right - just realized FromAsyncPatterns are one-offs which essentially can't be restarted, and that they Begin when referenced, not when subscribed.

Replacing

```
_resolver(host)
```

with

```
Observable.Defer(() => _resolver(host))
```

seems to do the trick.

If no-one objects (and I don't discover other problems), I'll accept this answer shortly.

Comment: Nailed it. You often want `Defer` when you use `Retry` or `Repeat`.